How to pass environment variables to Start-Process using ArgumentList?
I'd like to be able to pass environment variables from one PowerShell process to another.
I have an "entrypoint" script, let's call it Script1.ps1. From Script1.ps1, I would like to pass an environment variable to Script2.ps1, which I start up via a Start-Process block.
Script1.ps1's Start-Process block:

$MY_ENV_VAR = "hello world!"

$arg_list = @(
    "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass", 
    "-NoExit",
    "-Command", ".\Script2.ps1",
    "-EnvVar $MY_ENV_VAR",
    "-ErrorAction Continue"
)

Start-Process 'PowerShell.exe' `
    -NoNewWindow `
    -ArgumentList $arg_list `
    -Wait


Script2.ps1
Write-Host "The message from Script1 was: $MY_ENV_VAR"

I want this to return "The message from Script1 was: hello world!", but it returns:
"The message from Script1 was:"
I would use the -Environment parameter that was added to Start-Process with pwsh version 7.4, but sadly, I need to use Windows' 10's built-in PowerShell as this runs as part of a suite of setup scripts for VMs that runs before one can install anything from the internet.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.4)

There are few reasons to use Start-Process in this case, but if you need to, such as when you need to launch a new process using Elevated Privileges, you can handle it as follows:
Using Start-Process when you must

First change -Command to -File.
Then, since you're using -EnvVar this will mean a parameter in
your script Script2.ps1.
Add that parameter with a
param block at the very top of the called script before anything else.

In summary the calling block in Script1.ps1 can be:
$env:MY_ENV_VAR = 'hello world!'

$arg_list = @(
    '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass'
    '-NoExit'
    '-File', (Convert-Path '.\script2.ps1')
    '-EnvVar', $env:MY_ENV_VAR
    '-ErrorAction Continue'
)

$startProcessSplat = @{
    Verb         = 'RunAs'
    ArgumentList = $arg_list
    Wait         = $true
    FilePath     = 'PowerShell.exe'
}

Start-Process @startProcessSplat

And script2.ps1 should be:
param($EnvVar)

Write-Host "The message from Script1 was: $EnvVar"

One last note - you can see the change from -NoNewWindow to -Verb 'RunAs', as these are mutually exclusive.
If you want -NoNewWindow functionality because you don't need to launch a new elevated session, avoiding Start-Process altogether is a better and easier approach, by calling powershell.exe directly:
Avoiding Start-Process altogether
$env:MY_ENV_VAR = 'hello world!'
powershell -File .\script2.ps1 -EnvVar $env:MY_ENV_VAR -ErrorAction Continue

Or by even just invoking the script directly:
$env:MY_ENV_VAR = 'hello world!'
.\script2.ps1 -EnvVar $env:MY_ENV_VAR -ErrorAction Continue

These two retain -NoNewWindow functionality.

I'll try this in the morning! Much appreciated for the quick and easy to understand reply. I think I had a good reason for using Start-Process a year ago when this script was in its infancy (I've dramatically simplified the example above), but it may not be necessary anymore.

@jkix np! so the reason you could want to use Start-Process is if you want to start the process asynchronously but in this case you're using -Wait this means it runs synchronously (it blocks your shell until the process finishes) so there isnt a reason you should need it here

Oh, I do use RunAs in a variant of this block. Would I need to use Start-Process then?

@jkix ahh then yes if you need elevated then it makes sense

I took this and implemented @mklement0's points, along with a couple tweaks to forge a working solution. Thank you both for your help! The key thing I needed to build off of what you'd written here was prepending $env: to the variable passed through everywhere: (1) where I originally defined it in Script1.ps1,  (2) when I passed it through to -ArgumentList, (3) when I referenced it in param() in Script2.ps1, and (4) when I actually used it in Script2.ps1. Making a quick edit to make your answer complete.

@jkix note that using param($env:EnvVar) is misleading in this case, when you assign $env:MY_ENV_VAR = 'hello world!' that variable is only on the process environment, if you start a new elevated process that variable no longer exist in that process environment. $env: should be removed in this case.

To complement Santiago's helpful answer:

$MY_ENV_VAR = "hello world!"

$MY_ENV_VAR is a shell variable, i.e. a variable only visible to PowerShell and only in the current session.
To define an environment variable by that name, use the following:
$env:MY_ENV_VAR = "hello world!"

In your specific Start-Process call, the powershell.exe child process would inherit the caller's environment, so that any code running there could simply access $env:MY_ENV_VAR; the same applies to direct invocation of a child process.
As Santiago notes, the use case in your question does not warrant use of Start-Process and direct invocation is the superior alternative (stream integration, automatic reporting of the exit code via $LASTEXITCODE).[1]
However, Start-Process is needed if you need to create an elevated (run-as-admin) child process, namely via -Verb RunAs.
In that case, the elevated process does not inherit the (non-elevated) caller's environment, and even selective additions to the elevated process' environment are categorically prevented (see this answer for details).
Therefore, a different communication mechanism must then be employed, such as the one you've chosen: passing the value(s) of interest as arguments on the process command line.

[1] For more information, see this answer and this guidance

Unfortunately, the solution I selected as correct, while extremely helpful, wasn't what I fully needed after all.
Another solution which may be helpful in the case of RunAs is to simply write out to an .env file (just a text file):
Script1.ps1
$env_var="My variable"
Set-Content -Value $env_var -Path "$env:HOME\.env" 

# ... remainder of script, terminating in the Start-Process block

Script2.ps1
# When it's relevant:
Get-Content "$env:HOME\.env"

This is was by far the least painful to implement, though it may not be ideal for production systems.
